# JavaScript: Two identical functions, one will not work

Tags: javascript

I have two forms that are on separate pages and have JavaScript functions to be run when the submit buttons are clicked. Here is the JavaScript:

```js
var confirmConsentShot = document.getElementById('confirmConsentShot');
var confirmConsentMist = document.getElementById('confirmConsentMist');

confirmConsentShot.onclick = function() {
    'use strict';
    var editForm = document.getElementById("editForm");
    var newP = document.createElement('p');
    confirmConsentShot.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    newP.innerHTML = '<img src="Image/loading.gif" width="40" height="40"><br /><span style="color: #00AA00">You are being redirected to electronically sign the Vaccination consent form.</span><br />';
    document.getElementById('loading').appendChild(newP);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
    editForm.setAttribute('action', '?p=submitShot');
    editForm.submit();
};

confirmConsentMist.onclick = function() {
    'use strict';
    var editFormMist = document.getElementById("editFormMist");
    var newPMist = document.createElement('p');
    confirmConsentMist.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    newPMist.innerHTML = '<img src="Image/loading.gif" width="40" height="40"><br /><span style="color: #00AA00">You are being redirected to electronically sign the Vaccination consent form.</span><br />';
    document.getElementById('loadingMist').appendChild(newPMist);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
    editFormMist.setAttribute('action', '?p=submitMist');
    editFormMist.submit();
};
```

The first one functions perfectly fine. I copied it and set it for use on the other page (both pages load the JS file containing this code).

After it didn't work, I tried changing the names of some variables and ID tags, but this shouldn't have been necessary because each page loads separately so there are no two elements with the same IDs, and the variables within the functions only have local scope to that function. Also, the original function (top one) continues to work flawlessly. The second function will still not work, it appears to not get called at all with no console errors.

I have found a workaround for the second function by changing it to a standalone named function and adding it to the element with the 'onclick=""' attribute but I still MUST KNOW why this code will not work. It is driving me insane.

With the workaround, it runs the EXACT SAME code perfectly fine.

Just for reference, here is the workaround that functions properly with the onclick attribute:

```js
function onMist() {
    'use strict';
    var editFormMist = document.getElementById("editFormMist");
    var newPMist = document.createElement('p');
    confirmConsentMist.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    newPMist.innerHTML = '<img src="Image/loading.gif" width="40" height="40"><br /><span style="color: #00AA00">You are being redirected to electronically sign the Vaccination consent form.</span><br />';
    document.getElementById('loadingMist').appendChild(newPMist);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
    editFormMist.setAttribute('action', '?p=submitMist');
    editFormMist.submit();
}
```

I can only figure that there must be something fundamental to JavaScript itself that I don't understand. If anyone could explain this to me, I'd be so grateful!

Comment: I removed the Code Snippets feature from your OP since they are useless without relevant HTML.

Comment: If your first code is executed on a page that does not contain **both** HTML elements, it will throw an error, because you can't do `onclick` of `undefined`. In the second example you gave, where you directly bind the `onclick` event in the HTML, there is no problem, because it's only bound if the element is present on the page. If you want to keep your first version, you need to add `if(typeof myElement !== "undefined"){ myElement.onclick = ... }`

Comment: @blex So console would give me undefined for the function that referenced an element that was not on the page, but the first function always worked and the second one didn't. I guess I just don't understand why the first function would work and the second one didn't. I didn't think an error mattered if that particular function wasn't to be called on that particular page.

Comment: @C.Stew I think you'll have a better understanding by looking at these 2 JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pf0j9znf/ and https://jsfiddle.net/1rms8ou1/ and maybe this third one even explains it better, look at what gets displayed: https://jsfiddle.net/tek27o3o/

Comment: Thank you @blex. The takeaway for me here is that once an error is thrown, the remaining script will not be executed. This includes when an element is not present that the code is expecting. Thank you for your help, I appreciate you sharing those examples with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to use the html DOM to assign an `.onclick` event to your element with an `id=confirmConsentShot`.

```
document.getElementById("confirmConsentShot").onclick = function(){myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
    'use strict';
    var editForm = document.getElementById("editForm");
    var newP = document.createElement('p');
    confirmConsentShot.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    newP.innerHTML = '<img src="Image/loading.gif" width="40" height="40"><br /><span style="color: #00AA00">You are being redirected to electronically sign the Vaccination consent form.</span><br />';
    document.getElementById('loading').appendChild(newP);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
    editForm.setAttribute('action', '?p=submitShot');
    editForm.submit();
}
```

You can also attach a `click` event with addEventListener like so:

```
document.getElementById("confirmConsentShot").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

... now create your function:

```
function myFunction() {
    //your function
}
```

As mentioned above, make sure your html objects do exist or you will get errors.